# How to open child of child depending on a value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I know this question is asked thousands of time but somewhere I make a mistake I think

I try to open select box depending value of  child and if the child value is ('COME_LATE') ill open child of a child.

```
 ;(function () {

        $('#absence').on('change', function (e) {
                var el = $(this);
                if(el.val()==='None')
                    $('#absence_type').hide();
                else {
                    $('#absence_type').show();
                }
            });

    })(); 

 ;(function () {

        $('#absence_type').on('change', function (e) {
                var el = $(this);
                if(el.val() !=='COME_LATE')
                    $('#Lessons').hide();
                else {
                    $('#Lessons').show();
                }
            });

    })(); 


<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3'>
<select id="absence" class="form-control">
<option value="NONE" selected>Student</option>    
<option value="1">Student 1</option>
<option value="2">Student 2</option>
<option value="3"> Student 3</option>

</select>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" id="absence_type" style="display:none">
<label>Absence Type</label>
<select class="form-control">
<option value="COME_LATE">COMELATE</option>
<option value="LEFT EARLY">LEFT EARLY</option>
<option value="DIDNT_COME">DIDNT_COME</option>
</select>
</div>




 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" id="Lesson" style="display:none">
    <label>Which Lesson</label>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2 EARLY">2 EARLY</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like your casing is incorrect. Shouldn't you be checking for 'COME_LATE'?

Comment: ah sorry I translated my values to english its actually COME_LATE I edited my question

Comment: Not clear what is happening now. Create a demo that reproduces problem. `NONE != None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're making a selection on the second combo box you need to find the value of the selected `option`. There was also a typo in your code - see the updated fiddle for a working example.

Taking the above into account, your JQuery would then look like the below:

[Fiddle example:](https://jsfiddle.net/rw7cb8c5/)

```
$('#absence_type').on('change', function (e) {
  //Find the selected option.
  var el = $(this).find('option:selected');
  if(el.val() !=='COME_LATE')
    $('#Lesson').hide();
  else {
    $('#Lesson').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('select').val()` returns same value as looking for selected option and is much simpler to use. Op's use of `$(this).val()` is perfectly valid

Comment: @charlietfl `$(this).val()` returns an empty value.

Comment: @charlietfl In OP's example "absence_type" is the `id` of the div. Therefore, on the `change` event, the value returned by `$(this).val()` is empty and `$('select').val()` returns 1.

Comment: OK...my bad...didn't look close at id , was only looking at the first one and assuming second was the same configurtion

Comment: still a  problem because `change `only binds to `<select>` not it's parent. That's partly why i was saying `$(this).val()` ...selector should be `$('#absence_type select')`

Comment: From what I gathered from the question, op wants the third combo box to appear if the value of the `select` is "COME_LATE". OP's original code already had the second combo box appearing, depending on the selection of the first. The issue was with the third combo box.

Comment: still can't bind a change event to a <div>

Comment: Selecting a value in the `select` still triggers the `change` event. If you look at the console of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw7cb8c5/2/), "change" is printed every time a selection is made.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are using [IIFE functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to wrap your jQuery code.

These are not the same as using `$(function()` or `$(document).ready(function()` which are both the same thing

Try changing

```
;(function () {
   /* your jQuery code */      
})();
```

To

```
$(function() {
   /* your jQuery code */
});
```

Also you can't bind a form control event to a `<div>`

Your second selector should be `$('#absence_type select')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document)
  .ready(
    function() {

      $('#absence').on('change', function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val() === 'None')
          $('#absence_type').hide();
        else {
          $('#absence_type').show();
        }
      });



      $('#absence_type').on('change', function(e) {

        var el = $(this);
        alert($('#absence_type option:selected').val());
        if ($('#absence_type option:selected').val() !== 'COME_LATE')
          $('#Lesson').hide();
        else {
          $('#Lesson').show();
        }
      });
    });
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5xkhb9u0/2/)